# Error on combining multiple excel files into one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

kindly help me to know where I am committing an error in the following command:
I am trying to combine more than 30 excel files into workbook with multiple worksheets. the error is occurring on the 8th row of the VBA code below shared. I appologize for I am not good at using VBA. thanks!

**VBA code being used is the following:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineMultipleExcelWorkbookIntoOne_OneSheet()
Dim Path As String, Filename As String
Path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\desktop test\"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Error code generated looks like the following:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Copy method of Worksheet class failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to save your workbook objects in a variable, and also I recommend to use  Sheets object when you  want to refer sheets by their index instead of Worksheets.
Try this inside your Loop

```
Dim Wbk As Workbook
Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
Wbk.Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Wbk.Close False
Filename = Dir()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally checked and found that the issue with my code was that I wrote it in another module that is not saved in the workbook I was working with, therefore it kept showing error when reaching to pasting the copied sheet to ThisWorkbook which was not my intentional. thanks a lot @BrunoQuintero for the prompt feedback!